# Put array elements with the same value into one element and concatenate their keys

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to merge/append the keys of array which contains the same values.

I have an array like this:

```
$array = array(
           '12' => 'Coats',
           '23' => 'Coats',
           '45' => 'Brushs',
           '5'  => 'others',
           '7'  => 'None',
           '8'  => 'None',
           '9'  => 'None',
         );
```

Expected output is:

```
$array = array(
           '12,23' => 'Coats',
           '45' => 'Brushs',
           '5' => 'others',
           '7,8,9' => 'None'
         );
```

My attempt:

```
$subFinalFinal = array();

foreach($array as $key => $val){
    if($skey = array_search($val, $subFinalFinal)){ //duplicate value
        $subFinalFinal[$key.','.$skey] = $val;
    } else {
        $subFinalFinal[$key] = $val;
    }

}
```

But it doesn't give me my expected result:

```
Array
(
    [182] => Coats & Jackets
    [211,182] => Coats & Jackets
    [45] => Brushs 
    [5] => others
    [7] => None
    [7,8] => None
    [7,9] => None

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through all unique values, which you get with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), with a foreach loop. Here something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Coats
    [1] => Brushs
    [2] => others
    [3] => None
)
```

And get all keys, which hold that unique value with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php). Means in this example:

```
     value     |        key(s)
--------------------------------------
     Coats     |     Array (12, 23)
     Brushs    |     Array (45)
     others    |     Array (5)
     None      |     Array (7, 8, 9)
```

Then you can [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) your  array of keys into a string and use it as key.

Code:

```
<?php

    $array = array('12' => 'Coats', '23' => 'Coats', '45' => 'Brushs', '5' => 'others', '7' => 'None', '8' => 'None', '9' => 'None', );
    $result = [];

    foreach(array_unique($array) as $uniqueValue)
        $result[implode(",", array_keys($array, $uniqueValue))] = $uniqueValue;

    print_r($result);


?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [12,23] => Coats
    [45] => Brushs
    [5] => others
    [7,8,9] => None
)
```

Comment: but what is the difference between your answer and Uchiha? Both are efficient?

Comment: @M3Dev Uchiha uses `array_flip()` to get the unique values (I use `array_unique()`) and he implodes the keys first into the value and flips the array back after that (I implode them in the key itself).

Comment: Ah, okay got this. Thanks Man!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_flip` as

```
$res = array_flip($array);
foreach($res as $k =>$v) $res[$k] = implode(", ", array_keys($array, $k));
print_r(array_flip($res));
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [12,23] => Coats
    [45] => Brushs
    [5] => others
    [7,8,9] => None
)
```

Comment: What is the difference b/w your answer and Rizier123's? Both are efficient?